# Lecture notes/book on conformal nets.

Tags: reference-request, mathematical-physics, conformal-geometry, von-neumann-algebras, quantum-field-theory

I am looking for introductory lecture notes or a textbook on conformal nets. It should be as self-contained as possible. I am particularly interested in learning about sectors. Preferably it would have examples of conformal nets, other than the ones associated to loop groups and vertex operator algebras. I believe one can construct a conformal net using the Clifford algebra associated to the Hilbert space $L^{2}(S^{1},\mathbb{C})$, a source where this example is treated in some way would be best.

I am aware of the [lecture notes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.05675) by Yasuyuki Kawahigashi, but they are far from self-contained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

André Henriques has written lecture notes on the topic: "Three-tier CFTs from Frobenius algebras" ([arXiv:1304.7328](https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.7328)) as well as more extensive [lecture notes on conformal field theory](https://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~henri105/Teaching/CFT-2014.pdf) for a course taught at Berkeley in 2014. Although they do not cover your entire wish-list, they are nicely written and self contained. You could also take a look at the PhD thesis of his student, Shan Shah, "Bicoloured torus loop groups" ([arXiv:1704.02600](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.02600)).

Comment: Thank you Jules! Especially the "lecture notes on conformal field theory" look very good, and from what I can see they include a description of the conformal net that I was alluding to in the question. I will leave the question open for a bit longer, but if nothing else comes up I will accept your answer.

Comment: @Peter You're welcome! I hope you're enjoying Germany :)

Comment: @Peter PS. A next time I would recommend MathOverflow for these kind of questions

Comment: I believe the lecture notes can now be found in http://andreghenriques.com/Teaching/CFT-2014.pdf

Answer (score 1):

In Antony Wassermann's paper [*Operator algebras and conformal nets*](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s002220050253.pdf) the free Fermion super conformal net was constructed using Clifford algebras. The conformal net for $LSU(N)$ was constructed as a sub-theory of free fermions.